# What is the function of nested do-while loop here in this Java guess game program?

Tags: java, do-while

I don't understand how the nested do-while loop could discard other characters and why is there a newline syntax. Could some one explains it, many thanks.

```
public class guessGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        char ch, ignore,answer='K';

        do {
            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
            System.out.print("Can you guess it:");

            //read a character
            ch=(char) System.in.read();

            //  ************ here ************
            do {
                ignore =(char) System.in.read();
            } while (ignore != '\n');
            //  ************ to here ************

            if (ch==answer) System.out.println("** Right **");
            else {
                System.out.print("...Sorry, you're ");             
                if(ch<answer) System.out.println("too low");
                else System.out.println("Too high");
                System.out.println("Try again\n");
            }
        } while (answer !=ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Input from the user until newline char is read and first char from the input is assigned to `ch` with this line:

```
ch=(char) System.in.read();
```

After that, rest of the input user entered is assigned to `ignore` variable. New line syntax basically tells the program that this is the last char from input stream.

After first char from the input is assigned to `ch`, code block inside `do` statement is executed once. If the second char user typed is `\n`, while statement becomes false and program continues to execute from next line of code. If the second char typed is not newline char, loop continues until newline char.

**Why is it needed?**

```
ch=(char) System.in.read();
//user enters ASDF\n
//ch is assigned as A
do {
    ignore =(char) System.in.read();//SDF\n is assigned to ignore
        } while (ignore != '\n');
```

If the inner do while above wouldn't exist, the outer loop would automatically assign `SDF\n` (*including newline char*) to `ch` from input stream one by one in every loop and each would be regarded as an answer from the user until input stream has no more chars left.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to reply in the comment.

The code which you has written above will get completed only when you are giving character 'K'. Inner do while is to skip the if-else statement when the character is /n.

Only when you are giving character 'K', the outer do-while will get satisfied and get completed.

For example -

**input character is 'A'** - It will print sysout statements and once again wait for the new input.
**input character is '/n'** - It won't print any sysout. But, it will wait for the new input.
**input character is 'K'** - It will print sysout as right and get completed.

Comment: thanks, but explain you please explain more specifically why if I type ABCD, only A will be counted, BCD will be discarded?

Comment: System.in.read()  - This method will return numbers between 0 to 255(2 byte). So, it will hold the only one character.   In order to read the complete string, You can use Scanner class or BufferReader.

Answer (score 1):

Your program behave in this way (in English):

Step 1 : accept a character followed by an Enter key (the newline character). 
Step 2 : if the character input is not answer, return to Step 1
Step 3 : print ** Right **

Now, there are two reasons the do ... while loop you mentioned is there.

First reason, user can type "abcdef" followed by an enter key.
For this case, the program only wants to take the first character 'a' to compare with answer. The rest are to be discarded. The do ... while is there to ignore "bcdef".

Second reason, in certain operating system, all linefeed ('\n') is proceeded by the carriage return ('\r'). For this case, one needs to ignore the carriage return.

```
public class guessGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        char ch, ignore,answer='K';

        do {
            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
            System.out.print("Can you guess it:");

            //read a character
            ch=(char) System.in.read();
            // Case 1 : assume user input "abcdef\n" here
            // Case 2 : assume operating system makes user input "a\r\n"

            //  ************ here ************
            do {
                ignore =(char) System.in.read();
                // Case 1 : "bcdef\n" is read in this loop
                // Case 2 : "\r\n" is read in this loop
            } while (ignore != '\n');
            // Case 1 : "bcdef" is ignored
            // Case 2 : "\r" is ignored
            //  ************ to here ************

            if (ch==answer) System.out.println("** Right **");
            else {
                System.out.print("...Sorry, you're ");             
                if(ch<answer) System.out.println("too low");
                else System.out.println("Too high");
                System.out.println("Try again\n");
            }
        } while (answer !=ch);
    }
}
```